# Wordpress Logged In Cookie and Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up GTM to avoid including any tracking JavaScript (GA, FB Pixel, Linkedin, etc) code for users logged in to the website. Only administrators can be logged in and the site is using WordPress so my theory is that simply checking that the WordPress logged-in cookie is set will allow me to add conditions to my triggers checking for the cookie.

The problem is that a 32-character hash is attached to the end of the cookie name. Something like this:
`wordpress_logged_in_c61670c29894a13760815de6f19b9544`

How do I check for this in GTM?

I would like to avoid adding custom code to the website if possible. I know that adding a quick PHP function to set and remove a cookie would be quick and easy. I'd just like to see how it could be done in GTM.

In GTM I have a 1st Party Cookie called DL - WP Login Cookie. I'm just not sure what to place in the Cookie Name field since the cookie name is different for each user.

Can this be done?

Comment: Could you create a Trigger but use the "Only some events.." option, and create a Custom JS variable that checks the cookie as a substring? Then you could just search for the non dynamic string in the cookie for whether or not it's present.

Comment: @DubVader probably a JavasScript variable would suffice (so not a "custom Javascript" with a function, just enter document.cookie in the variable configuration for the Javascript variable - after all, this is a global JS property in the browser). This  would technically meet the "no custom code" requirement, but I think would still fail with strict CSPs, if that is the worry.